# Strange results using Linux find

Tags: linux, bash, find

I am trying to set up a backup shell script that shall run once per week on my server and keep the weekly backups for ten weeks and it all works well, except for one thing...

I have a folder that contains many rather large files, so the ten weekly backups of that folder take up quite a large amount of disk space and many of the larger files in that folder rarely change, so I thought I would split the backup of that folder in two: one for the smaller files that is included in the 'normal' weekly backup (and kept for ten weeks) and one file for the larger files that is just updated every week, without the older weekly versions being kept.

I have used the following command for the larger files:

```
/usr/bin/find /other/projects -size +100M -print0 | /usr/bin/xargs -0 /bin/tar -rvPf /backup/PRJ-files_LARGE.tar
```

That works as expected. The tar -v option is there for debugging. However, when archiving the smaller files, I use a similar command:

```
/usr/bin/find /other/projects -size -100M -print0 | /usr/bin/xargs -0 /bin/tar -rvPf /backup/PRJ-files_$FILE_END.tar
```

Where $FILE_END is the weekly number. The line above does not work. I had the script run the other day and it took hours and produced a file that was 70 Gb, though the expected output size is about 14 Gb (there are a lot of files). It seems there is some duplication of files in the large file, I have not been able to fully check though. Yesterday I ran the command above for the smaller files from the command line and I could see that files I know to be larger than 100 Mb were included.

However, just now I ran `find /other/projects -size -100M` from the command line and that produced the expected list of files.

So, if anyone has any ideas what I am doing wrong I would really appreciate tips or pointers. The file names include spaces and all sorts of characters, e.g. single quote, if that has something to do with it.

The only thing I can think of is that I am not using xargs properly and admittedly I am not very familiar with that, but I still think that the problem lies in my use of find since it is find that gives the input to xargs.

Comment: _"many of the larger in that folder files rarely change."_  Most backup scripts use hardlinks to save space in this situation.  Fortunately, you don't have to reinvent the wheel.  Just install a backup script like [`rsnapshot`](http://www.rsnapshot.org/) and use it.

Comment: Thanks. I am still curious about what I am doing wrong with find, but I had a look at rsnapshot and it seems quite interesting!

Comment: rsnapshot also has competitors that you may want to consider: dirvish, ccollect, among others.  With regard to your `find`+`tar` commands, if there was any clear problem with them, I expect that someone would have posted an answer by now.

Comment: Ok. Many thanks for taking the time to comment. I will have a look at the other options that you mention too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I do not know if it is considered bad form or not to answer your own question, but I am doing it anyway since I realised my error and I wanted to close this and hopefully be able to help someone having the same problem as I had.

Now, once I realised what I did wrong I frankly am a bit embarrassed that I did not see it earlier, but this is it:

I did some experimental runs from the command line and after a while I realised that the output not only listed all files, but it also listed the directories themselves. Directories are of course files too and they are smaller than 100M so they have (most likely anyway) been included and when they have been included, all files in them have also been included, regardless of their sizes. This would also explain why the output file was five times larger than expected.

So, in order to overcome this I added `-type f`, which includes only regular files, to the find command and lo and behold, it worked!

To recap, the adjusted command I use for the smaller files is now:

```
/usr/bin/find /other/projects -size -100M -type f -print0 | /usr/bin/xargs -0 /bin/tar -rvPf /backup/PRJ-files_$FILE_END.tar
```

Comment: It is perfectly fine to [Answer your own quesition](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: If files over 100MB go in LARGE.tar, and files under 100MB go in PRJ.tar... where do files of exactly 100MB go? ;-)

Comment: @Mark Setchell: Ha! Yes, it did actually occur to me when I set those rules up since I normally take that into account when working with limits, but since this is a hobby project and I am not sure how I would acheive that using find I have chosen to ignore it, for now at least. Should I ever get a file that is exactly 100M, I will have to solve the problem (or add a little text file to the 100M file).